# convert string cell to array of integers

Tags: java, sql, arrays, database

[image: cell in Access DataBasse]

I want to covert this attanched cell which is stored in DataBase As string type 
to float array in my code after i retrieve it from the DataBase  
For example:

```
float [9] EX  = new float[0.152, 0.253, 0.102, 0.304, 0.355, 0.355, 0.152, 0.203, 0.203];
```

Can any one help me !
Regrads!

Comment: There are no integers as integers are no fractions... As you showed in your example you probably want to store them as `double`s or `float`s (but I would probably prefer double). Anyway what stops you from doing so? Do you need help with getting string from DB, splitting this string into tokens, parsing token to double, storing parsed value in array?

Comment: You say convert to an array of ints, but then in your code block you have a float array. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First divide your input string into parts by `String#split`, then parse values:

```
String input = "0.123 0.234 0.456";  // <= string from DB cell
String[] ss = input.split("\\s+");   // <= split using whitespaces as splitter
float[] f = new float[ss.length];    
int i = 0;
for(String s : ss) {                 // <= iterate over separate values
     try {
          f[i++] = Float.parseFloat(s);
     } catch (RuntimeException e) {
          System.out.println(s + " cannot be converted to float");
     }
}
```

Comment: Salay ou
i used this code but Instead of String input = "0.123 0.234 0.456";
i wrote String input= res.getString("Array1"); 
but gave me this error SEVERE: null
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: invalid cursor state: identifier cursor not positioned on row in UPDATE, DELETE, SET, or GET statement: ; ResultSet is positioned before first row

Comment: @Beba.S stacktrace you provided says definitely the problem regards database access, not string processing.